# how to do a Unit Test with Junit and mockito in java on methods that prefer dates

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm new to Junit and Mockito Testing in Java, can someone give me an example or an idea of ​​how I can test a method that basically converts a date that is received as a parameter:

```
public static String fileAEDateFormat(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = null;
    Date dateFecha = null;
    DateFormat dateFormat = null;
    String fecha = null;
    try {
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ConstantsFiles.DATE_FORMAT_CM);
        dateFecha = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ConstantsFiles.DATE_FORMAT);
        fecha = dateFormat.format(dateFecha);
        logger.info(fecha);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        logger.error(ConstantsFiles.PARSE_EXCEPCION + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return fecha;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, and built into Java 8+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need any mock here since your method does not seem to be communicating with any external api/service/object.

The Junit assertion will be along the lines of

```
@Test
void given_a_date_string_should_provide_expected_output_format(){
   assertEquals("expected output", MyClass.fileAEDateFormat("input"));
}
```

Comment: Kurojin I run it with your example and it doesn't give me an error, if it runs it, but junit tells me Failures 1, is that normal or why does it show that?

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz If the test failed, that means the expected output was not equal to the actual output (i.e., `assertEquals` threw an assertion error). Note you aren't supposed to run the code in this answer exactly as is; you're supposed to replace `"expected output"` and `"input"` with your actual output and input. If you did that, then look at the test failure message to see what the actual result was, and then figure out why your method fails to return the expected result.